# How can i set double height to Imageview programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview

Image view takes int value programmatically but in some time height calculate in double so any one have suggestion which one procedure. I searched but did not get exact solution

Here is my code:

```
//--------calculate width and height
        int final_width;
        double final_height;
        final_width  = width - 40;
        final_height = ((final_width) * (0.75));
        Log.e("final height",""+final_height);
        imageView.getLayoutParams().width  = Utility.pxToDp(final_width,mContext);
        imageView.getLayoutParams().height = Utility.pxToDp(final_height,mContext);
```

Comment: Try cast double to int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got a solution here is code for help to any person

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        mContext.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
        int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        Log.e("width",width+""+height);


        //--------calculate width and height
        int final_width;
        double final_height;
        final_width  = width - 40;
        final_height = ((final_width) * (0.75));
        int height_final = (int) (final_height + 0.5f);
        Log.e("final height",""+height_final);
        holder.homeFragmentBusinessImageView.getLayoutParams().width  = final_width;
        holder.homeFragmentBusinessImageView.getLayoutParams().height = height_final;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
final_height=final_height+final_height
```

Thats what I would do to get a 2x effect on height.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum range of int varies from 2147483647
-2147483648. So int is enough, you don't need a double. Otherwise you can typecast your value to int.

```
int intVal = (int) Math.floor(val);
```

> where value of val=some float.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code it's move layout height by pro-grammatically.

```
 private void moveOffScreen() {

        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        int screenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;

        int offset = (int) (screenHeight * 0.50); /* percent to move */

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams rlParams =
                (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) mChart.getLayoutParams();
        rlParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, -offset);
        mChart.setLayoutParams(rlParams);
    }
```